# Count a specific quantity of li elements and move them to a new div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i count the first thirteen li elements and move them to a new div (slide1), after that count the next thirteen li elements and move them to new div (slide2) and so on?

```
selection = [1-13];
    for(var i=0; i<selection.length; i++) {
    jQuery('li').eq(selection[i]).append('.slide1')
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code and show what you've tried.

Comment: The first thing you should do is start writting your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/U2vjd/1/)

**Supposing this your HTML structure**

```
<ul>
  <li />
  ...
</ul>
<div id="slide1"><ul /></div>
<div id="slide2"><ul /></div>
...
```

**jQuery**

```
$("li").each(function(i){
    i++
    $slideNum = Math.ceil(i/13);
    $("ul","#slide"+$slideNum).append(this);
});
```

Comment: I guess instead of going with .each it is better using slice

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can go for jQuery's slice method.

Here is the API documentation for the same: http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Have a look.

In case you wonder about the usage

This is the perfect working solution.

```
$ ("div#first")    .append ($("ul li").clone().slice (0,12));
$ ("div#second")    .append ($("ul li").clone().slice (12));

jQuery ("ul").remove();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GB3BR/